# Ansible remote controllers / slaves

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to get Ansible commands to run in a master/slave setup, where commands are started on a master Ansible server and get run on the remote/slave Ansible servers?

Jenkins/Bamboo/etc have similar concepts.

Reason for this is having Ansible run commands in different AWS accounts and VPCs, on instances that are not publicly available.

The ProxyCommand works fine for linux instances, but running commands on Windows instances in private subnets has proven to be very difficult. Running the commands on an Ansible instance local to that VPC may be an alternative to trying to use a jumphost/bastion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such slave concept in Ansible. The `ProxyCommand` option is as close to your description as it gets.

You are probably aware that Ansible cannot be run on Windows *as the control machine*, and I assume that you want to configure a Windows host, but you cannot connect directly to that host.

In case you can connect to a (Linux) machine in the same network, you could simply install Ansible on that host, and run the commands remotely using a playbook that runs remote playbooks, e.g. using `shell` (possibly with `async`).
There is an [Ansible role to install Ansible](https://galaxy.ansible.com/geerlingguy/ansible) for the bootstrapping.